# Difference between "fluency" and "fluidity"

Tags: semantics

*Fluent* seems to most commonly refer to language mastery, but in that context isn't it just saying that its delivery is *fluid*?

If so, am I communicating something different when using one over another or are they essentially interchangeable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will compare the adjectives *fluent* and *fluid*.

The etymologies of the words are [shared](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fluid) and so is one of the meanings:

> smooth and unconstrained in movement

So, when you speak about *movement* (literary or as metaphor), it is interchangeable.

Otherwise it is not:

> **fluent**
>   - easy and graceful in shape
>   - expressing yourself readily, clearly, effectively
>
> **fluid**
>   - characteristic of a fluid; capable of flowing and easily changing shape
>   - subject to change; variable
>   - affording change (especially in social status)
>   - in cash or easily convertible to cash

NOTE:
If you read the etymology entry, you will find that fluent was

> Used interchangeably with fluid in Elizabethan times.

Comment: So is the difference that both would cover the "flowing" nature of a liquid, but only Fluid would extend to other liquid properties?

Comment: @SamuelHulick, no. Not the whole difference. Read the answer again.

Comment: Also, I will leave as an exercise for you to compare the definitions of nouns that are made from these adjectives (what your question is really about). The situation changes there. I recommend www.onelook.com

Comment: I think [linguistic fluency/fluidity](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=linguistic+fluency%2Clinguistic+fluidity&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) provides a bit of an edge case here. The former relates to people's ability to use language well, the latter to the fact that language itself is always shifting.

Answer (score 5):

As a second language teacher, I constantly run into theories about fluidity and fluency. Fluency is a more complicated issue than fluidity. Fluency includes the skill of being able to express specific content (often spontaneously) with ease. Fluidity has more to do with speed of speech, intonation, rhythm. For example, a person who pauses and hesitates a lot would not have achieved fluidity. One can be fluent without being fluid, and one can be fluid without being fluent. Fluidity is more attached to style and delivery, and fluent is more attached to content and ease of communication. Fluidity is often a sub-category of fluency.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to language, I would say that you should be fluent in a language before you can be accused of fluid delivery. Fluent means "*Able* to express oneself readily and effortlessly" ([tFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluent); italics mine). I am fluent in English, but not everything I say is delivered fluidly. The other meaning @Unreason gave ("easy and graceful in shape") does not apply to language mastery.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not interchangeable. You can be fluent in a language, but you can't be fluid in it.

Comment: Dude that was covered in the first sentence of my two-sentence post.

Comment: @Samuel: Dude, you noticed that 'fluent' is mentioned in the context of languages a lot. You didn't say anything about 'fluid'. Barrie is telling you that 'fluid' really is quite a bit more general than fluent (there are contexts where fluent is too specific), and in contexts where language is relevant, you would prefer 'fluent' over 'fluid'. This is despite the obvious fact that there share a lot in their nominal definitions.

Comment: @Mitch I did mention 'fluid' - it's the last word of that sentence. I'm asking if saying that someone speaks a language with *fluency* is the same as saying someone speaks a language with *fluidity*. Responding that "you can't be fluid in" a language negates the premise and isn't valuable without further elaboration, imo.

Comment: @Samuel: Dude, if you're going to be rude to people who try to help you, you're liable to find that there are fewer and fewer interested in offerring assistance.

Comment: @Samuel:you can say 'fluid in a language' but it sounds really wrong, like you badly mispronounced 'fluent'. If you really really really mean 'fluid' in a language' it's like you're trying -not- to use 'fluent' and so it accentuates the literal meaning of fluid. That is, it's not a perfect synonym of 'fluent'.

Comment: @Mitch The words in the post title are "fluency" and "fluidity". I don't know why anyone would think I'm asking if "fluid in a language" is appropriate.

Comment: @Jay Fair enough. I'm grateful for help, but I don't see how this answer provides any info on what I'm asking. This also isn't the first time I've gotten an answer from this particular user that appears as though they only skimmed the post and dashed out something off-target. Either way, point taken - I will make sure to keep my future SE contributions respectful going forward.

Comment: @Samuel: same thing goes for what I said replacing the adjectives with the nouns.

Comment: @SamuelHulick, the other reason why you are perceived as rude is also the fact that you are asking a question that can be answered with a straight lookup into a dictionary (or so it seems since you did not make a case why the dicitonary entries would not be helpful, in the question itself). According to the faq such questions should be closed as general reference and not answered. To such a question Barrie offered a short and essentially correct answer. To this you reacted like you did. Anyway, welcome and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe fluency refers to your knowledge of the language, i.e, using concise language, whereas fluidity refers to flow of speech. I live in Poland and it is incredibly irritating to listen to otherwise very intelligent people speak because they pause after a few words and utter loudly "ehhhhh" or "mmmmm" then continue with their conversation, repeating these irritating interruptions to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I asked for the comparison of fluent vs fluid because I reread my email to a friend which said,"I see I can't write fluidly either."  I still don't know whether or not I should have used "fluently" instead. Now I question my lack of fluency.

Comment: My question is the similar to number 3 above.  I wanted to know if the use of 'fluidly' in my sentence should have been 'fluently'

Answer (score 0):

Fludity vs. Fluency. 
Fluency is only at the level of what the other person HEARS. In the speech cylce Fluency only refers to what is coming out of your mouth, and limits itself to that ONLY.

Fluidity is a more complex socio linguistic term. Roland Barthes (look him up) refers to much more. the relation between signifier and signified. IOW: it refers not only to what is coming out of your mouth, but also what is going on in your mind as a thought process and its relation as a whole to the linguistics cycle.