# Can the word 'fluently' be interchanged with 'fluidly' in this sentence, "I see I can't write fluidly either."

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

I was asking a question concerning the use of the words 'fluently' or 'fluidly' in a particular sentence.  I did not mean to post it as an Answer.

Comment: You can delete your answer, by clicking the ["delete" link underneath it](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/192904/300). And you should move over its content into the body of this question, by clicking the "edit" link here. Right now not only is your answer a question, but your question is a meta post rather than a question.

Comment: And remember that questions showing reasonable research (or at least details of attempts) are preferred.

Comment: I would prefer "to speak fluently" and would leave "fluid" to the chemist.

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for *fluent*:

> **fluent** *adj* (1585) **1 a :** capable of flowing : FLUID **b :** capable of moving with ease and grace {the *fluent* body of a dancer} **2 a :** capable of using a language easily and accurately {*fluent* in Spanish} {a *fluent* writer} **b :** effortlessly smooth and  and flowing : POLISHED {a *fluent* performance} {spoke in *fluent* English} **c :** having or showing mastery in of a subject or skill {*fluent* in math}

So if you were wondering whether *fluently* applies only to spoken language (as you might suppose if you considered only the second example after definition 2b above), you needn't worry: The adverbial form of *fluent* definition 2a comprehends both spoken and written English, as the second example after it illustrates.

As for whether you can use *fluidly* in your original example, one definition of the adjective *fluid* in the Eleventh Collegiate is

> **2 :** characterized  by or employing a smooth easy style {the ballerina's *fluid* movements} {*fluid* recitation of his lines}

Considerable overlap exists between *fluent* definition 2b and *fluid* definition 2; and this overlap applies to the adverbs *fluently* and *fluidly* as well. An Ngram Viewer chart of "write fluidly" (blue line) versus "write fluently" (red line) for the years 1820 through 2008 indicates that the latter is more common in the publications included in Google Books' database:

[image]

But "write fluidly" is by no means uncommon in books published over the past several decades, including such serious works as Julia O'Brien, editor, [*Oxford Encyclopedia of the Bible and Gender Studies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZU-nBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA176&dq=%22write+fluidly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-misVLaAL8bxoASx2oKAAg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAjha#v=onepage&q=%22write%20fluidly%22&f=false) (2014):

> Not all texts used in some form of public instruction were copied out by individuals who were able to **write fluidly**. The commentary on Habakkuk from Qumran was apparently copied out letter by letter.

In short, you can use *fluidly* or *fluently* in the sentence “I see I can't write fluidly/fluently either,” and convey much the same meaning either way.

Comment: The two mean different things to me (and the example seems to agree). Writing _fluently_ implies writing well, in a flowing, well-worded, mellifluous manner that results in a pleasant read. Writing _fluidly_ implies joined-up writing, not taking your hand off the paper, conjoining successive letters.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I wouldn't limit _fluidly_ to describing the physical process of writing cursively, but the Oxford example certainly has that meaning. Another match from the same set (Castagno, [_New Playwriting Strategies_](https://books.google.com/books?id=chWpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA216&dq=%22write+fluidly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ooasVP-xCcP1oASjloDYAw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22write%20fluidly%22&f=false), 2011) has this: "This fundamental technique must be mastered for the playwright to write fluidly within an episodic structure." Here, _fluidly_ seems to mean "without awkward transitions."

Comment: ...Both _fluidly_ and _fluently_ have a strong sense of "flowingly," whether that term is understood metaphorically or literally. Your short definition of _fluently_ is extremely well put, and I think that _fluidly_ generally lacks the same degree or aspect of mellifluousness or perfect aptness; nevertheless, it does describe flow and (I think) can do so figuratively.